# Inline span with min-width on IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Hi
I have 3 `SPAN` that must be `inline` and have and a `min-width`.
Apparently on IE, the `SPAN` can't have an `min-width`. I try to use `DIV` but when I put it `inline`, the `min-width` is ignore.

CSS

```
span {
    display: inline;
    min-width: 150px;
}
```

HTML

```
<span>1</span>
<span>2</span>
<span>3</span>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`inline` element can't take `width`, `height`, `vertical margin` & `padding`. So you have to define `display:inline-block;` write like this:

```
span {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;/* for IE7*/
    *zoom:1;/* for IE7*/
    min-width: 150px;
}
```

Source: [Cascading Style Sheets Level 2 Revision 1 (CSS 2.1) Specification: 10.3 Calculating widths and margins: 10.3.1 Inline, non-replaced elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-width):

> The 'width' property does not apply. A computed value of 'auto' for 'margin-left' or 'margin-right' becomes a used value of '0'.

check this http://jsfiddle.net/yCvhB/5/

Comment: Works in Firefox but not in IE.

Comment: +1 - edit works for me. I see `zoom:1` causes an `inline-block` effect for IE7/IE8, which I did not know. Would you mind adding how that works to your answer?

Answer (score 1):

you could use padding.
since you made the element inline there is no point of specifying min-width.

Comment: There is text in the span add in ajax. All the text don't have the same size so I want an min-weight. Most of the time the text will me smaller than the span and the display will be the same but something, the text can be longer.

Comment: well.. then i guess you need to use float:left; making the display attribute to "block" and then clear the float later.<br />
bloody IE eats all the developer time..!

Comment: +1 for the padding idea, which helped me out with a contenteditable that would otherwise have zero area to click in.

Answer (score 1):

Basing my answer on [sandeep's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274841/inline-span-with-min-width-on-ie#9274889), you can use

```
span {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    *zoom:1;
    width: auto !important;
    width 150px;
    min-width: 150px;
}
```

and it should work. Check out this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ramsesoriginal/yCvhB/2/

internet Explorer has some problems with minimum widths and heights, but at the same time it has problems with `!important`, so exploiting that (and the fact that without specifying overflow every with is a min-width for IE) we can have something working.