# Make Html Generic Control span entire cell even when it's empty

Tags: html, css, asp.net, htmlgenericcontrol

I have a Html Generic Control (with a span in it), which when clicked runs a Javascript method. I also generate text within the control (read: span) which describes editing rights for every user in the table. I then put that control into a cell within a `asp:table`.

The problem is that it only runs the method when I click the text generated, which is fine as long as the user has any editing rights. When a user doesn't the cell doesn't contain any text.

My question is, how can I make the span cover the entire cell, empty of text or not?
I want to be able to click the cell and run the method.

Oh, also the span is entered through the controls InnerHtml. I don't know if that matters but there you go. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use sytle for the `Html Generic Control`.
Set it's width to a fixed width like `width:100px` or `min-width:100px;`. 
Suppose the id of the span is `spn_Msg` then you can use like this

```
  spn_Msg.Style.Add("min-width", "100px!important");
```

Or, I have tested this, will definitely work, please check

```
 spn_Msg.Attributes.Add("class", "yourClass");
```

and in the class

```
 .yourClass{
     display: inline-block;
     *display: inline;/* for IE7*/
     *zoom:1;/* for IE7*/
     min-width: 150px;
 }
```

### Source

[Inline span with min-width on IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274841/inline-span-with-min-width-on-ie)

Comment: Nope, didn't do it for me. The problem is that the span doesn't cover the entire cell. But I think I know how to solve the problem instead. Will try to attach the click to the cell itself instead.